# CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll saves a black image

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, camera-roll

I'm using react native's cameraRoll to save an image i got from taking a screenshot with react-native-viewShot.

I get the screenshot and the image saves to my camera roll. My problem is that the image saved has a black background. I don't know how to fix this.

```js
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri)
```

That is the code I use to save the image.

Why does it save a black image?

Comment: have you validated that the uri is correct?

Comment: @skrusetvtI didn't. I didn't think I needed to I got the URI from my screenshot using https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

Comment: I remember when I was using a URI path to upload, I had to use this library in order to get the actual path.  
 https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [ViewShot library](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) you will have to give background colour to the ViewShot otherwise it will give black default colour hence it is showing black image.